# Notifications system in Sf/WS/SQL: performance considerations

Tags: php, mysql, performance, notifications

*Note: I'm not sure about the tags I chose, feel free to add or remove some.*

I will implement a notification system on a commercial website of my company.
The traffic will not be enormous but at least consequent.

I have some technical choices to do. Below are my thoughts. I'm just expecting some remarks or advices :)

- The number of unread notifications cannot be fetched at each *"classic-static-http-request"* (eg. when the user arrives on my site, then browse it with good old hypertext links).

  - The solution: an Ajax request at the first page load on a new session. The number of unread notifications is then stocked into the JS's `sessionStorage`.
- As Facebook does, notifications will be displayed instantaneously, thanks to a websocket server daemon written inside my Symfony app. This let me use Doctrine, Response objects and other swag services. When a notification is sent to the browser, the `sessionStorage` entry is incremented.

  - I think that, today, Ajax long-polling is harder to implement than a simple WebSocket server. Also, this is lighter than repeating Ajax requests. Support for ancient browsers isn't crucial but I think I will need to develop some fallbacks for IE (websockets arrived in v10, thanks Microsoft)
- **The most important question:** The notifications are currently (I just begun to work on it) stocked in a MariaDB (=MySQL) database. I use a Doctrine entity. Do you think the performances will be fine? Read notifications won't be stored for more than few days. But all notifications are stored in one place (=table). The table will handle a lot of requests (automatic deletes, very frequent inserts, and then a lot of reads/changes).

  - Is a noSQL engine necessary or something like this ? Or a more complex system between a MariaDB storage for long-term persistance and a cache engine like Redis as a swap zone?

Comment: You've got a lot of questions in your question. While I think there is a lot of interesting discussions possible, I don't think this is a good fit for Stack Overflow. It might be better to split your question up into Programmers Stack Exchange and maybe the DB Stack Exchange? (though double check that your question(s) are on topic there). While saying that, a general rule of thumb is to not double post across sites so avoid doing that by removing the question here.

Comment: You're probably true. If nobody give some interesting answers here, maybe I will post more specific posts on the other StackExchanges.